# Expression.Property(param, field) is "trolling" me [System.ArgumentException] = {"Instance property 'B.Name' is not defined for type A"}

Tags: linq, exception, lambda, expression

Once again, I am facing an issue, this time with LINQ Expression builder and this time I am even struggling to find the reason why it's not working. I have a Database-First EF project with quite a few tables. For this specific case, I have to use 2 of them - DocHead and Contragent. MyService.metadata.cs looks like this:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(DocHead.DocHeadMetadata))]
public partial class DocHead
{

    // This class allows you to attach custom attributes to properties
    // of the DocHead class.
    //
    // For example, the following marks the Xyz property as a
    // required property and specifies the format for valid values:
    //    [Required]
    //    [RegularExpression("[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*")]
    //    [StringLength(32)]
    //    public string Xyz { get; set; }
    internal sealed class DocHeadMetadata
    {

        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private DocHeadMetadata()
        {
        }

        public string doc_Code { get; set; }
        public string doc_Name { get; set; }
        public string doc_ContrCode { get; set; }
        //...

        [Include]
        public Contragent Contragent { get; set; }
    }
}

[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Contragent.ContragentMetadata))]
public partial class Contragent
{

    // This class allows you to attach custom attributes to properties
    // of the Contragent class.
    //
    // For example, the following marks the Xyz property as a
    // required property and specifies the format for valid values:
    //    [Required]
    //    [RegularExpression("[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*")]
    //    [StringLength(32)]
    //    public string Xyz { get; set; }
    internal sealed class ContragentMetadata
    {

        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private ContragentMetadata()
        {
        }

        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //...
```

I take some docHeads like this:

```
IQueryable<DocHead> docHeads = new MyEntities().DocHead;
```

Then I try to sort them like this:

```
docHeads = docHeads.OrderByDescending(x => x.Contragent.Name);
```

It is all working like I want it. I get those docHeads sorted by the name of the joined Contragent. My problem is that I will have to sort them by a field, given as a string parameter. I need to be able to write something like this:

```
string field = "Contragent.Name";
string linq = "docHeads = docHeads.OrderByDescending(x => x." + field + ")";
IQueryable<DocHead> result = TheBestLinqLibraryInTheWorld.PrepareLinqQueryable(linq);
```

Unfortunately, TheBestLinqLibraryInTheWorld does not exist (for now). So, I have set up a method as a workaround.

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField); // normally returns x.sortField
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param); // normally returns x => x.sortField
        string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp); // normally returns sth similar to q.OrderBy(x => x.sortField)
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

Normally... yes, when it comes to own properties of the class DocHead - those prefixed with doc_. The disaster strikes when I call this method like this:

```
docHeads = docHeads.OrderByField<DocHead>("Contragent.Name", true); // true - let it be Ascending order
```

To be more specific, the exception in the title is thrown on line 2 of the method OrderByField():

```
var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
```

In My.edmx (the model), the tables DocHead and Contragent have got a relation already set up for me, which is the following: 0..1 to *.

Once again, I have no problem writing "static" queries at all. I have no problem creating "dynamic" ones via the method OrderByField(), but only when it comes to properties of the class DocHead. When I try to order by a prop of the joined Contragent class - the disaster strikes. Any help will be greatly appretiated, thank you!

Comment: I've never thought LINQ was trolling me, but I get that feeling a lot with XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`Expression.Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341554(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not support nested properties. It does exactly what it says - creates expression that represents a property denoted by `propertyName` parameter of the object denoted by the `expression` parameter.

Luckily it can easily be extended. You can use the following simple [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) / [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) trick anytime you need to create a nested property access expression:

```
var prop = SortField.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)param, Expression.Property);
```

Comment: Thank you for your 100% working solution! Cheers!
@Ed Plunket - Sometimes, just for fun, I replace the word 'throws' with the phrase 'is trolling me', because 'throw' and 'troll' sound very similarly, when pronounced. To be honest, I do my best to avoid writing linq queries for data like 'from t in tt select' - this particular syntax is really trolling my mind. 'Normal' queries with lambdas have always seemed more friendly to me.